Whistling gas boiler pipes
I have a new boiler in the basement of a 3 floor house (incl basement) and a Grundfos water pump (ups15-58frc), which has 3 speed settings. We moved in 5 months ago and all worked fine but in the last month we have a whistling sound thru the pipes that enter image description hererun from the boiler thru the house which gives off an annoying and constant noise. The plumber (person who installed) came and said there is nothing wrong and turned down pump to lowest level and the sound stopped. He left and now we realize at low pump level, we have no hot air!
We think the pump has an issue. There is no screw on front to bleed and we don’t know what we should do. The pump is under warranty but the rep won’t come out unless the plumber requests, which he won’t!
Any ideas welcome, please

Please add photos.

how do i add photos?
